# Is there a way to programmatically call button press animation without calling the method?

Tags: java, android

**Update: I just added a second set of buttons above with no method so the two would not interfere.**

**To be clear, the following is for a simon says type game, where the computer plays a pattern of buttons and the user must click them in the correct order.**

I am calling programmatically a sequence of buttons as a demo to the user, who is expected to press those buttons. But as the demo buttons are pressed their methods are being called which is messing up things for the user.

How can I call just the button animations so that the demo is still presented but the onClick methods are NOT called?

Here is some relevant code:

```
public void clickBut(View view, int[] list, int level) {

    Button redBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.redBut);
    Button blueBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.blueBut);
    Button greenBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.greenBut);
    Button yellowBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yellowBut);

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        if (list[i] == 0) {
            redBut.setPressed(false);
            redBut.performClick();
            redBut.setPressed(true);
            redBut.invalidate();
            redBut.setPressed(false);
            redBut.invalidate();
        }
        else if (list[i] == 1) {
            redBut.setPressed(false);

            blueBut.callOnClick();
            blueBut.setPressed(true);
            blueBut.invalidate();
            blueBut.setPressed(false);
            blueBut.invalidate();
        }
        else if (list[i] == 2) {
            redBut.setPressed(false);

            greenBut.callOnClick();
            greenBut.setPressed(true);
            greenBut.invalidate();
            greenBut.setPressed(false);
            greenBut.invalidate();
        }
        else if (list[i] == 3) {
            redBut.setPressed(false);

            yellowBut.callOnClick();
            yellowBut.setPressed(true);
            yellowBut.invalidate();
            yellowBut.setPressed(false);
            yellowBut.invalidate();
        }

    }
}
```

Forgive me if the setPressed(boolean) lines are superfluous or erratic I'm trying out different combinations.

I need this to play and click the correct buttons without activating the methods, then open it up to the user so he/she can click buttons and have the appropriate methods called.

Let me know if any more of the code would be helpful.

Comment: What about disabling the buttons?

Comment: please post some code so that I can understand..

Comment: @Pablo that sounds promising, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: Why you don't just save a state that you are currently in a demo and in the methods which are called from the button listeners, you check the state and do nothing if in state demo?

Answer (score 2):

Replace-

```
        redBut.setPressed(false);
        redBut.performClick();
        redBut.setPressed(true);
        redBut.invalidate();
        redBut.setPressed(false);
        redBut.invalidate();
```

by-
     following code to appear button clicked for 1 second:-

```
            button.performClick();
            button.setPressed(true);  
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //called after 1000 millisecond/ 1 second
                    button.setPressed(false);  
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

And If you want to show button selected then use-

```
            button.setPressed(true);
```

Comment: the line buttonsetPressed(true) will make the button appear as if it were pressed?

Comment: yes button.setPressed(true); will make button appear pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(null);
```